# PostgreSQL column name as keyword in two table

Tags: postgresql, keyword

I have 2 table1 and table2

```
table1
id,desc

table2
id,t1_id,desc
```

how i can select row depending on desc="something"

```
select * from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.t1_id 
where t1.desc='something'
```

there is data in table 1 having desc "something" but its returning nothing

i tried

```
where "desc"='something'
```

but giving

> ambiguous column desc error.

how i can retrieve data from table 1 where desc='something' in postgreSQL

many thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `"` to escape reserved keywords.

```
select * from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.t1_id 
where t1."desc"='something'
```

But don't forget to add the table name or alias if a column is named equal in 2 tables. The DB engine does not know which one to take if you don't specify the table.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you are looking for is:

```
SELECT * from table1 JOIN table2 AS t 
ON t.t1_id = table1.id WHERE table1.desc='something'
```

Comment: finally found problem... had to use trim(t1.desc) = 'something'